# Three "easy" matches with SQL REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

I've got a problem that probably has a very easy solution, but I can't figure it out. Maybe you can :D

I have a column that contains strings with any number of 't's or 'f's. So some typical strings are:

```
tttttt
fffff
ftft
t
f
ttftfttf
```

What I need are three different REGEXPs for a MySQL query: one that matches strings with only 't's, one that matches strings with only 'f's, and one that matches strings with at least one 't' and at least one 'f'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Only `t`'s

```
^t+$
```

2. Only `f`'s

```
^f+$
```

3. Contains at least one `f` AND one `t`

```
^(t+f+|f+t+)+f*t*$
```

Comment: Your third regex does not match `ftf`

Comment: Nice try, but now it doesn't match `ftff` :P

Comment: @Andomar: I knew you would mention it! Caught it before you! Try another exploit...

Comment: Can't find a problem with that one.  It looks similiar to Gordy's answer :)

Comment: @Adomar: Yeah, I just checked his answer, however, he is using too many unnecessary backreferences.

Comment: In the end, I settled for "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP 't' AND column REGEXP 'f'", because for a very specific reason, I cannot use "*" in my queries. But your answer seems to work, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

all t's: `^t+$`

all f's: `^f+$`

t's and f's: `^(t|f)+$`

t's and f's that doesn't match the first two: `^((t+f+)|(f+t+))+(t|f)*$`

Comment: But `^(t|f)+$` would match an all-t string, like `tttt`

Comment: Thanks! The first two work great, but the last one returns a match when the string contains all 't's or all 'f's, and I need it to return a match only when the string contains at least one 't' AND at least one 'f'

Comment: maybe you can test the 3rd only if the first two don't match? I added one that should match t's and f's but not all t's or all f's

Answer (score 0):

only f's = [^t] 
only t's = [^f]
at least one t = t
at least one f = f

Comment: I dont quite get it, could you please explain it a little?

Answer (score -1):

Start of string, followed by one or more `f`s, followed by end of string:

```
^f+$
```

String containing either `ft` or `tf`, and any amount of other `t`s and `f`s:

```
^[ft]*(ft|tf)[ft]*$
```

Comment: I tried that last REGEXP, and it throws me an error... is it just me?

Comment: @LFS: It works on my MySQL installation, `select * from test where col1 regexp '^[ft]*(ft|tf)[ft]*$';`